# Rename WAMP Server

Tags: apache, wamp, server, mediawiki, windows-server-2012

I have WAMP running on a Server 2012 R2 (virtualized) server in a Windows AD Domain. I am hosting a Wikimedia site off of it.

I renamed the server from SERVERNAME01D to SERVERNAME01P and noticed, in ADUC, that it renamed OK. I performed an ipconfig /registerDNS` on the server and I can ping the server by server name only.

When I browse to the server, I receive:

Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server.

- Hosts file just has 127.0.0.1 localhost and ::1 localhost entries.
- httpd.conf only references localhost, not a server name.
- I updated the LocalSettings.php entry for server name.

From the server itself, I can navigate to the wiki page perfectly with both host name, FQDN, and 'localhost.'

Does anyone have a suggestion of where to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit confusing, but I was able to get it to work.

In the httpd.conf file, I added appropriate IP ranges. It had been set to deny all other than localhost. I am not sure why it worked prior to changing the server name though...